# Where to store constant strings

Tags: objective-c, ios

In my app i have about 30 strings i would like to store somewhere. I want to use it in couple classes later, and it will be used only once in every class. Where is the best place to store it? I read about singleton class in ios, but i'm not sure if this is solution for me.

I want to make something like NSArray where in ***for*** loop i can search the array.

I've tried to define it like:

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"something",@"else", nil];
```

But i can do it in .h file, and i'm not sure if for constant variables i want to have a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you don't mind, you can have a plist file with an `NSArray` and all your `NSStrings` inside of it, then to load them:

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myArray" ofType:@"plist"];
NSArray *myArrayOfStrings = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

The Singleton pattern is a solution, but for what the op wants, a plist is more than enough.

Comment: When i do that, and want to access myArray from plist i'm getting in plistPath nil (0x00000000). I'm trying to access from *application didFinishLaunching*.. and myArray in [AppName]-Info.plist have 5 items. Why?

Comment: Oooh, i find out what's wrong. This is a separate plist file.

Comment: For a moment I though you were not adding the plist file in the application's bundle.

Answer (score 1):

For an Array, you can't!
Constants are created at runtime, and you can initialize them with an expression.
You can declare a convenience class method, that returns the array, and use static NSArray * arr, within that method, treating it as a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the "MyProjectName_Prefix.pch" which lies into the "Other Sources folder". All the includes and defines putted there are included with each class of your project.
The best way to go in your case would be, IMHO, that you put all your constants into a "myStringConstants.h" file and then include that file from the "MyProjectName_Prefix.pch".

Comment: But how to declare there a NSArray contains NSString?

Comment: I see you edit your answer but how to declare NSArray with NSStrings in h file. This is my major issue.

Comment: I misunderstood your question. If it's an object that you need to share across your application, then as you mentioned, the Singleton pattern would be your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain C style:

```
NSString* const arr[] = {@"something",@"else"};
const int arrSize = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

void printArr()
{
    for(int i=0; i<arrSize; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%@", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

To declare prototypes in .h file use `extern` :

```
extern NSString* const arr[];
extern const int arrSize;
```